# what /proc files are preserved across reboots

Tags: linux

A lot of settings can be tweaked using magic files in `/proc` (for example, `/proc/sys/kernel/core_uses_pid` which names core dump files with the pid).

Which settings are preserved across reboots and which ones do I need to refresh every time?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Nothing in /proc is directly preserved across reboots.  The /proc filesystem is a 'pseudo' filesystem that reflects state inside the running kernel and isn't a reflection of state on any persistent storage medium.

Some stuff has the impression of being preserved because scripts in /etc/init.d/ (or /etc/rc.d, or whatever init-script convention your system uses) that are run at startup will set values in /proc.  Try: grep -r '/proc' /etc/init.d/*

Comment: Take sysctl.  If you make changes through the sysctl program, those changes are not preserved.  However, settings in /etc/sysctl.conf are reflected in each reboot.  Is there an equivalent magic file?

Comment: There is no generic equivalent magic file for preserving settings in /proc to sysctl.conf.  There are probably other .conf files that will impact some parts of /proc, but nothing generic.  Most init scripts do something like: "echo 0> /proc/sys/dev/raid/speed_limit_min" (this is from hdparm).

Comment: @FooBah: using `sysctl -w` _is_ equivalent to writing to `/proc/sys/`, just append `kernel.core_uses_pid = whatever` to your `/etc/sysctl.conf` file.